# Polars more concise way to replace empty list with null

Tags: python-polars

**Question overview**

I am extracting data from a newline-delimited JSON file by applying a series of transformations.  One of my transformations results in a list of values; for cases where the list is empty, I want the value to be null rather than an empty list.  I have code that works, but it seems very convoluted and I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do this that I am missing.

**More detail**

In each JSON object of my ndjson file, one of the data elements I'm interested in is an array of `telecom` nested JSON objects.

```json
{
   ... some data
    "telecom":
        [
            {
                "rank": 1,
                "system": "phone",
                "use": "work",
                "value": "(123) 456-7890"
            },
            {
                "rank": 2,
                "system": "fax",
                "use": "work",
                "value": "(123) 456-7891"
            }
        ]
    ... some other data
}
```

As part of a larger data extraction operation, I am doing:

```py
df.select(
   expr_first(),
   expr_extract_phone(),
   expr_others()  
)
```

where `expr_first()`, `expr_extract_phone()` and `expr_others()` return Polars expressions that perform some transformation on various fields of my dataset.

For `expr_extract_phone()` I want to get a list of phone numbers from `telecom` as follows:

- for each nested object in the `telecom` array, extract `value` where `system=="phone"`
- collect all the individual phone numbers in a list
- if the list is empty, the value of the column should be `null` rather than `[]`

I have been able to cobble together something that works:

```py
def expr_extract_phone() -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col('telecom').list.eval(
            pl.element().filter(pl.element().struct['system'] == 'phone').struct['value']
        ).list.unique().alias('phone_numbers').map_batches(lambda col:
            pl.LazyFrame(col).select(
                pl.when(pl.col('phone_numbers').list.len() > 0)\
                .then(pl.col('phone_numbers'))
            ).collect().get_column('phone_numbers'),
            return_dtype=pl.List(pl.String),
            is_elementwise=True
        )
```

Getting the list of phone numbers seems straightforward enough, however the entire `map_batches` portion to replace an empty list `[]` with a null value seems very convoluted.  Is there a simpler way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

For strings [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72292048/idiomatic-replacement-of-empty-string-with-pl-null-null-in-polars) seems to provide a nice clean way to handle but I can't seem to find an equivalent for a list.

Comment: `map_batches` was only needed for your previous question because that is how we can encapsulate a dataframe operation (i.e. `.join`) inside a *"single expression"*.

Comment: Got it!  I guess you taught me how to use a screwdriver to open screws and now you find I'm also using it as a can-opener ;)
For others who may come across this, this is what jqurious is referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78190236/12309386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed column of type `pl.List(...)`, you could simply use an `pl.when().then()` construct as follows.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [[1, 2], [3], [], [4, 5], [], [6]]
})
```

```
shape: (6, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ a         │
│ ---       │
│ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╡
│ [1, 2]    │
│ [3]       │
│ []        │
│ [4, 5]    │
│ []        │
│ [6]       │
└───────────┘
```

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("a").list.len() > 0).then(pl.col("a"))
)
```

```
shape: (6, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ a         │
│ ---       │
│ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╡
│ [1, 2]    │
│ [3]       │
│ null      │
│ [4, 5]    │
│ null      │
│ [6]       │
└───────────┘
```

The only complication in your concrete example stems from the fact that you don't have a fixed column given but need to apply the construct to an expression. This can easily be done, by saving the `pl.Expr` in a intermediate variable.

```py
def expr_extract_phone() -> pl.Expr:
    phone_numbers_expr = (
        pl.col('telecom')
        .list.eval(
            pl.element().filter(pl.element().struct['system'] == 'phone')
            .struct['value']
        )
        .list.unique()
        .alias('phone_numbers')
    )
    # reuse expression from before
    return pl.when(phone_numbers_expr.list.len() > 0).then(phone_numbers_expr)
```

**Warning.** While polars usually caches repeated sub-expressions, it currently doesn't in cases when the repeated expression is of the form `pl.Expr.list.eval`. Especially, `phone_numbers_expr` may be (partly) recomputed.

Comment: Perfect!  I had considered when-then but was concerned that the repetition would make my code harder to read and would have a performance cost; your answer addresses both of these.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to actually do `with_column(phone_numbers_expr)` first, and then run `pl.when`, as phone_numbers_expr could be evaluated twice (when and then)

Comment: @MarkWang As far as I can tell using `with_columns()` is not possible in the context described by OP. However, I don't think the expression is evaluated twice. When inspecting the query plan in a lazy context using `.explain()`, `phone_numbers_expr` gets a separate alias that is used in both parts of the `pl.when().then()` construct. This suggests to me that polars is aware of the duplicated expression and will optimize accordingly. Do you know a way to check whether any duplicate computation is done?

Comment: @Hericks might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76508578/why-doesnt-polars-reuse-the-already-evaluated-results-of-repeated-expressions-w

Comment: @MarkWang Great! As Dean MacGregor mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77397929/12978930), caching common sub expressions is already implemented.

Comment: I get separate `col("telecom").eval().list` instances in both the `when` and `then` sections of the `explain()` output.

Comment: @jqurious You are right. I tried this locally only with a simpler example. It seems like `[...].list.eval()` expressions are never cached. Do you have any more insights on this (open todo, not possible, bug)?

Comment: I have not seen it mentioned before. `map_elements` cannot be cached: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13895 - I am unsure if `list.eval` has this same restriction (or if it just has not been implemented as of yet?)

Comment: Some further digging: Apparently `list.eval` executes what Polars considers an *"opaque function"* and they appear to have had CSE disabled since `0.19.2` https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/10905/

Comment: Trying to follow along with the discussion.  If I understand correctly...
1. the expression that actually extracts the phone number value is being used in two places (once in the `when`, again in the `then`).
2. when used within a `list.eval` it is not cached (looks like this is to prevent incorrect results as described in https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10901)
3.  therefore, the code proposed by @Hericks will work, but may not be the most efficient.
Is that the gist of it?

Comment: @teejay Yes, list.eval seems to be ignored by the `comm_subexpr_elim` optimizer so will execute twice here. Normally, one could just do `.with_columns(pl.when(col) != []).then(col)` separately but because you want to isolate the behaviour into a single expression - it complicates things.

Comment: @jqurious I understand.  Would then my original approach actually be more optimal?  Or does `map_batches` introduce its own inefficiencies?
@Hericks in order for your original answer to also be useful to others who may land here, may I recommend you update it to reflect the fact that the sub-expression will not actually be optimized?

Comment: @teejay Done! Regarding the comparison, I'd still bet on fully relying on polars native expression API. However, for your concrete example it might be best to benchmark the runtime of the two approaches. I'd be very interested to hear about the result.

Comment: @teejay I'm not sure. list.eval runs [as a group_by internally](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/8199/files). So while CSE does not appear to activate here, I don't think it's a simple case of: *"All of this work will be duplicated, causing runtime to double."* - Polars also caches groups (among other things), has work parallelism, etc. Benchmarking with your specific dataset would be interesting as Hericks has suggested.